# Static/Non static classes and methods

Tags: c#

Lets assume i got this class:

```
public class Utlities
{
   int Age;

   public static void DoSomething()
   {
       Age ++;
   }
}
```

My questions to this:

1. Does anyone from outside - can access DoSomething() in same time? - assuming YES
2. If answer on 1. is YES then if couple classes executing this method the value will be changing without any problems?
3. Class is non static but method is static so is the method only accessible one time in specific time?
4. What in case i have couple instance of that class if other classes will access specific instance of class Utilities true is that DoSomething method will be shared/the same across all instances of class Utilites or for each instance of Utilities class other outside classes will be accessing different DoSomethingmethods?

Lets take another example:

```
public class Utlities

    {
       static int Age; // <------------------------------------

       public static void DoSomething()
       {
           Age ++;
       }
    }
```

How it will be in this case?

And last:

```
public static class Utlities  //<-------------static now
{
   static static int Age;

   public static void DoSomething()
   {
       Age ++;
   }
}
```

As class is static now all inside have to be static - does it mean that only one outside class can access it in same time?

Last questions as i want to create some help class which inside i would have common methods that could be useful in my program should i use static class with static methods or non static class with static methods - please of explanation here as well.

Comment: Well your first example wont even compile. You can't access an instance field in a static method.

Comment: Can you point to a guide/manual/website/book you are using to study C#? I'm pretty sure even the most basic book will cover these topics profusely.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable/class/method as static wont change the accessability.

As an example, a `static` method belongs to the class itself, meanwhile a nonstatic method belongs to each object of that class.

If you have a static variable

```
static int ageCounter;
```

all objects of the class, holding this variable, will see the same `ageCounter`

In addition to that, your question was about multiple calls of that static method by different classes. If this happens in a single thread you wont have problems at all. Trouble starts if different threads try to work on the same data.

Comment: so its not about accesability - either static or not multiple classes can access to it except treading case then i need to use lock right?

Comment: @StackUser exactly. Imagine a `class Bike` if this Bike would be static, everyone would use the exact same Bike. If it is non static, everyone would get his very own Bike. So if it comes to multithreading, and everyone want to ride the same `static` bike, its understandable that it'll come to a crash

Comment: and if Bike would be non static and got method Ride as non static/or static then when i would create instance of it and fire multithreading to fire Ride of that instance then i would need lock anyway right?

Comment: @StackUser if the method `Ride` is non static and the class `Bike` is non static, and you create for every thread an instance of `Bike` you dont have to lock anything. Every call of `Ride` would refer to that threadspecific `Bike`-Object

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that your first example will not compile (can't access instance field from a static method), `static` doesn't restrict use of that method. It is entirely possible that multiple thread access that method at the same time.

Instead `static` means that you can access that method (or field) without an instance of that `Utlities` class.

You can just use

```
Utlities.DoSomething();
```

instead of (which doesn't even compile)

```
var myutls = new Utlities();
myutls.DoSomething();  // <-- compile error: cannot be accessed with an instance reference
```

In the `static class` example, you can't even do a `new Utlities()`. The compiler will not accept it (Cannot create an instance of the static class).

Be careful with a static value like that `static int Age`: this means that your application can store just *one* Age value (which isn't always what you want)

Answer (score 0):

(Presuming that your `Age` field was meant to be `static`, too.)

Declaring a variable/class/method as static wont change the accessability.

As an example, a `static` method belongs to the class itself, meanwhile a nonstatic method belongs to each object of that class.

In addition to that, your question was about multiple calls of that static method by different classes. If this happens in a single thread you wont have problems at all. Trouble starts if different threads try to work on the same data.

Last, you mentioned the missing `static` modifier on the `class`. That modifier is only there to prevent a class from being instantiated and can be used if (and only if) all members of the class are static, too.

Comment: 1. If static non-static class has 1x static method and 2x non static methods - then all instances of it has their own copy of 2xnon static methods but all of them sharing the same 1xstatic method. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you just copypasted stuff from my answer :D?

Comment: 2. If class is static the i cannot make an instance of it but call methods directly and outside classes can access thier methods in same time without any problems besides if appliaction working in threading mode.
 3. If application working in thread mode and class is static - methods inside needs lock but if the class is non static but methods are or from the other hand class is not static and methods non static do i need lock as well?

Comment: @StackUser 1 -> yes 2 -> yes 3 -> you need to lock if diff threads work on the same data. If you create an object of a non static class for every thread you dont need to lock it because every thread will have his very own object

Comment: so all about memory and not accesability either static or not (without thread case) If class is non static and have 1xstatic method/field and 2xnon static field/methods then if i will make 4 instance of that class does each of them would have their own copied of those 2x methods and all will share this 1xstatic method so assuming i have got value inside this static method and some instance will change it within this method then all other instances will see this value?